# Use Key-Value Edit when passing object in Postman post request

Tags: postman

I have a collection of requests I'm trying to improve and want to be able to use the Key-Value Editing UI in Postman, but I need to pass an object.

```
rest_data = {
    "session_id":"{{sessionId}}",
    "dealer_number":{{integralinkCode}},
    "customer_id":"12345",
    "vehicle_id":null,
    "phone":"5555555555",
    "amount":"0.01",
    "reference_no":"test1234",
    "asm_user_id":"{{userId}}",
    "message":"test"
}
```

Currently, I have the key set as "rest_data", and the value holds the object. This works, but I feel like it makes it a bit hard to read. Ideally, I'd like to have the properties of the object as key-value pairs in Postman.

[image]

I tried setting the keys in Postman like this `rest_data["session_id"]` and the value equal to the relevant value, but that didn't work.

My reasoning is so that when making changes to the body, it's easier and I can fill in the description for values and what they should be. Also, you're not able to hover over environmental variables to see their values or use environmental variable autofill within the object.

Can this be done, and if so, how? I'm also open to alternative solutions.

Comment: I'm afraid you couldn't do that, because there're will be 2 different keys then BackEnd cannot understand to extract data.

Comment: I was afraid that was going to be the case. Thanks anyway!